# How to obtain Dirac equation from Schrodinger equation and special relativity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, schroedinger-equation, dirac-equation, klein-gordon-equation

I'm reading the Wikipedia page for the [Dirac equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation):

> *The Dirac equation is superficially similar to the Schrödinger
>   equation for a free massive particle:*
>
> A) $-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2\phi = i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\phi.$
>
> *The left side represents the square of the momentum operator divided
>   by twice the mass, which is the non-relativistic kinetic energy. 
>   Because relativity treats space and time as a whole, a relativistic
>   generalization of this equation requires that space and time
>   derivatives must enter symmetrically, as they do in the Maxwell
>   equations that govern the behavior of light — the equations must be
>   differentially of the same order in space and time. In relativity,
>   the momentum and the energy are the space and time parts of a
>   space-time vector, the 4-momentum, and they are related by the
>   relativistically invariant relation*
>
> B) $\frac{E^2}{c^2} - p^2 = m^2c^2$
>
> *which says that the length of this vector is proportional to the rest
>   mass m. Substituting the operator equivalents of the energy and
>   momentum from the Schrödinger theory, we get an equation describing
>   the propagation of waves, constructed from relativistically invariant
>   objects,*
>
> C) $\left(\nabla^2 - \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\right)\phi = \frac{m^2c^2}{\hbar^2}\phi$

I am not sure how the equation A and B lead to equation C. It seems that it is related to substituting special relativity value into quantum mechanics operators, but I just keep failing to get a result...

Comment: Dirac himself talks about how he derived most of his ideas in this great lecture video he did in 1973. A little shaky, but very informative on the background of his ideas. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vwYs8tTLZ24&list=PLjNexov924eRr3L8aCirRyVCRN5rGi29W[](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vwYs8tTLZ24&list=PLjNexov924eRr3L8aCirRyVCRN5rGi29W)

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10837/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, C) isn't the Dirac Equation, it's the [Klein-Gordon equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein%E2%80%93Gordon_equation)

Now, to your main question.  A) comes from the classical equation for a free massive particle:

$\dfrac{p^2}{2m} = E$

by making the operator (operating on $\phi$) substitutions:

$p^2 \rightarrow - \hbar^2 \nabla^2$

$E \rightarrow i \hbar \dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}$

C) comes from B) by further recognizing that:

$E^2 \rightarrow -\hbar^2 \dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}$