# What are the relative limitations of the Schrödinger, Pauli, and Dirac Equations?

Tags: schroedinger-equation, dirac-equation

I know there are significant differences in the nature of the Schrödinger, Pauli, and Dirac equations. Although I know a bit about how each works, I don't understand the relative limitations of each equation relative to the others in terms of their usefulness in describing physical phenomena. 
For instance, the Schrödinger equation is not relativistically invariant, so the Dirac equation would be more suitable if you are working with a relativistic problem/situation.

Can someone summarize some of the crucial applications each equation relatively more useful than the others (if any)?

Note: if someone sees what I'm driving at and can edit this to make it better articulated, that would be great.

Comment: Here the simplest one: Dirac and Pauli equation can't describe spinless particle, while Schroedinger equation can do that. [:)].

Comment: Reallly?!? Amazing! I had no idea. I knew Klein Gordon, but if I recall there's some issue with that being the wrong order derivative.

Comment: Both the Dirac equation and the Klein-Gordon equation fail to make much sense if you attempt to use them as single-particle wave equations. They both require the "correct" interpretation, which is in the context of quantum field theory. When you mix relativity and QM you're inevitably led to many-particle systems, where particles can be created and destroyed.

Comment: @jld Does QFT permit single particle descriptions as manifestations of field quanta? Forgive me if that question makes no sense. I am just starting to learn about QFT.

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that many people would say that the Schroedinger equation is, in general, $$\mathrm{i}\hbar \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}|\psi\rangle = H |\psi\rangle,$$ where $|\psi\rangle$ is the quantum state vector and $H$ is the Hamiltonian operator. This equation is universally valid in quantum theory, including QFT.

Comment: Presumably the OP actually refers to the Schroedinger equation for non-relativistic theories, in which the kinetic energy operator is $p^2/2m$ etc.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10837/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Schrodinger equation describes the time evolution of a *non-relativistic* quantum state:

$$ i{\frac {\partial }{\partial t}}|\psi \rangle = H | \psi \rangle $$

The Klein-Gordon equation describes relativistic spinless particles, but being a 2nd order differential equation, it gives rise to unphysical negative probability densities:

$$ (\partial^{{\mu }}\partial_{{\mu }} + m^{2})\psi =0 $$

The Dirac equation comes from linearising the K-G equation, is relativistic and describes fermions, i.e spin $1/2$ particles. It also naturally describes anti-particles. It is worth to note that solutions to the Dirac equation are automatically solutions to the K-G equation:

$$ (i \gamma ^{\mu }\partial _{\mu } -m)\psi =0 $$

Finally, the Pauli equation is just a modification to the Schrodinger equation to incoropate spin interactions of fermions with an external electromagnetic field described by a vector potential $\mathbf{A}$, therefore it is still non-relativistic:

$$ \left[{\frac {1}{2m}}({\boldsymbol {\sigma }}\cdot ({\mathbf {p}}-q{\mathbf {A}}))^{2}+q\phi \right]|\psi \rangle =i\hbar {\frac {\partial }{\partial t}}|\psi \rangle $$

Comment: Do the Schrödinger and Pauli equations work for any particle then? Also, which of those four equations (if any) can be used with hadrons?

Comment: Pauli describes spin 1/2 particles in an electromagnetic field, but the Schrodinger equation describes the evolution of quantum mechanical states. The Schrodinger equation can describe quantum systems, not just particles. Basically anything that has an associated evolution with it!

Comment: Hmm. So is the Schrödinger equation special in this regard relative to the other four? Or can all of them be used to describe the evolution of quantum states?

Comment: In a hand-wavy way the Schrodinger equation is more general than the other cases. The others describe more specific things due to the introduction of spin.